ArcGIS Pro contingent values, feature template automation?
I am exploring ArcGIS Pro contingent value feature to see if it works for my case.
End goal is looking to create a fgdb with bunch of feature classes, containing domains, and contingent values, and feature templates for a end user to use.  For them to easily create a feature that has all the correct values pre applied.
Current test gdb contains 1 point feature class with approx 12 attributes, and 6 domains.
I have created scripts to automate all the domain loading, assign domains to appropriate fields, create the field group
As a long-time ArcMap user, I am starting to explore ArcGIS Pro, particularly its contingent value feature, to see if it suits my needs. My ultimate goal is to create a file geodatabase (FGDB) containing various feature classes with domains, contingent values, and feature templates for end users. This setup will enable them to easily create features with all the correct values pre-applied.
Currently, my test geodatabase includes one point feature class with approximately 12 attributes and 6 domains. I have written scripts to automate domain loading, assign domains to the appropriate fields, create the field group, and load all possible contingent value combinations (over 100).
However, when I try to create a point (single symbol) in map mode with the feature class loaded, I encounter an error: "Attribute does not satisfy a required Contingent Value." I can then access the attributes and drill down to the specific field group criteria for the 6 fields, which allows me to create the point successfully.
Is there an easier way to automate this step? Am I missing something obvious? Ideally, I want to create the template using the default contingent value (CV) presets, rather than manually creating the 100+ entries.
